# iframe with colorbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

my head part is

```
<head><title></title>
<link href="css/style-custom.php.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/layout-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/skeleton-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js?ver=1.0"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {    
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements    
    $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "45%", height: "50%" });
});

</script>     
</head>
```

and the link which open iframe is here....initially it was working but after adding master page it stopped working...please provide me solution for it.

```
<a href="ForgotPassword.aspx" class="iframe" style="padding-left: 20px;">Forgot Password</a>
```

---

Comment: can you write the code for me in jsfiddle so that i can understand the problem clearly?

Comment: your question is incomplete, where is the link?how have u added master page?.....

Answer (score 3):

Check your developer console for errors.  And you probably don't mean to be loading jQuery twice (both the unminified and minified versions).

Comment: You are much too kind and diplomatic, Jack. ;)